# How to include a .lib file dynamically?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qmake

I've got a problem with my project. I am developing it on Qt Creator, and I need to add a .lib file to my project. So, I wrote this line in my .pro :

```
LIBS += "C:\My_Path\My_Project\lib\file.lib"
```

This is working fine. My only issue is that I need to write the entire path to the .lib file. Since it's a group project, it needs to be compilable on other computers without changing the path to this file every times.

I tried many syntaxes, like :

```
LIBS += -L"lib/" -l"file.lib"
```

or

```
LIBS += "lib\file.lib"
```

or

```
LIBS += "file.lib"
```

(putting the .lib file at the root and adding it to the project in Qt Creator)

None of them works :/

I also tried to add the .lib file in a QResource file but a syntax like this one :

```
LIBS += ":/lib/file.lib"
```

in a .pro file doesn't seem to work...

I am now running out of ideas :(

Help please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution :

the lib/ directory has to be placed in the same directory that the Makefile (the real one, not the .pro).
Since I copied the lib/ directory in the build-desktop/ directory, everything is working fine using relative paths :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try

`LIBS += -Llib -lfile`

or

`LIBS += -L./lib -lfile`?

Remember if you aren't using the full path, you don't add `.lib` to the library name and you don't use quotes.  If the path has spaces (or you just want to be safe), use `$$quote(-L<path name>)`

As stated [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qmake-variable-reference.html#libs) the Unix style paths work on Windows as well where you normally need to provide the full path.  qmake will fill it in for you.

I converted

`LIBS += ../../lib/phraseBox.lib`

to

`LIBS += $$quote(-L../../lib) -lphraseBox`

and

`LIBS += $$quote(-L../../lib) phraseBox.lib`

In one of my project with no problem on Windows.  You might want to post your project files somewhere, or post the actual error messages to narrow this down.

Comment: Still not resolving my problem. I still get a "cannot find file.lib". Here is the ultimate line I tried : LIBS += -L$$quote(./lib) -l$$quote(portaudio_x86). On the doc you linked, it's written we can add the .lib extension. Moreover, it's said numbers at the end of the file name can cause troubles. I tried to remove them but it's the same. Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: Even if I write it with an absolute path : LIBS += -L$$quote(C:\My_Path\My_Project\lib) -l$$quote(portaudio_x86) I get the same error :/ Are you sure the -L and -l options are available on Windows ?

Comment: My mistake, it says to do $$quote(-LC:\My_Path\My_Project\lib). I'll update my answer with another example, hold on.

Comment: Still the same :( I tried many syntaxes, got always the same error message "portaudio_x86.lib: No such file or directory". I saw you used "../../". It's specific for your project isn't it ? MyPro.pro and the lib/ directory are on the same level in the file hierarchy. Is that correct ?

Comment: @Nonepse: yes, that means its up 2 directories.  Please post your .pro files and outputs to something like gist.github.com or something.  I can't solve this without more information.

Comment: @Nonepse: please go to the compile output window and show the error and remove the OTHER_FILES part.

Comment: I answered my own question. My problem was lib/ was at the same level than project.pro, but not at the same level than Makefile. So I wrote LIBS += "../MyProject/lib" and it's working ;) Thanks for your help btw :)

Answer (score 0):

From your tries I guess you want to link to the library using relative path which should work just fine by default.

Try this:

```
LIBS += -L$$relative/directory/path -llibname
```

If it does not work, then you might want to try setting multiple [`INCLUDEPATH`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qmake-variable-reference.html#includepath). :/

Comment: So what's wrong with my use of LIBS += -L -l ? How do I have to use $$relative ?

Comment: The whole thing is weird, because it should work even without the $$, but it's woth the try imo.

Comment: INCLUDEPATH is not used for libraries, only included files.